# How to hide specific split window tab in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3, tabs

If I press "Alt+Shift+8", I can split sublime into 2 windows. And I want to hide the tab of one window(just as shown in figure [hide only one tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkZp0.png)). But If I click "Hide Tabs" in "View"(just as shown in figure [click "Hide Tabs"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85KwX.png)), all tabs will be hidden(just as shown in figure [all hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRb2N.png)). But I only want to hide one specific tab. How to achieve this?

Comment: That seems like a feature that is not implemented, so I'd post this here: https://forum.sublimetext.com/c/ideas-and-feature-requests